# How to access objects within a document in cloud firestore?

Tags: cloud, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using cloud firestore in my flutter app.

I have a document which has an object in it and the object in turn has a few key-value pair in it.

Something like this:

```
child "jamesjr",
message
Time August 19, 2018 at 12:00:00 AM UTC+5:30
msgbody "Hello, This is the first private message model"
pic1 "https://www.bing.com/th?id=OIP.HXmR02Xik3jiwFr8aN6NyQHaD4&w=269&h=149&c=7&o=5&pid=1.7"
pic2 "https://www.bing.com/th?id=OIP.Y11MMH-KHgXj0GyJJKC3lgHaFJ&w=255&h=177&c=7&o=5&pid=1.7",
reciever "wjames",
sender "steaher" ,
```

[image: A document with an object 'message' - screenshot from the cloud firestore]

Now, I understand that I can access the key-value pairs at the top level of the document by using

```
Text('${ds['child']}')
```

but, how do I read '`msgbody`' under the object '`message`' in my document?

*Thank you in advance*